# How to recompile red5 code at WEB-INF?

Tags: compilation, red5

i have editing a opensource code of red5. But i don't know how to recompile it. I use javax at cmd but can't run.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you read the documentation, or the product's web site?

Answer (score 0):

To compile Red5 you need to install [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and run `ant` in the main Red5 source directory where the `build.xml` file is located, or import the sources into Eclipse and build it there.

The latter method is probably much better if you want to modify the source code. There're some video tutorials made by Dominick Accattato [available on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/dominickaccattato#p/c/9B94807E1D0AF2DE). He talks about building Red5 from sources in one of them.